# How do I work with static file server?

Tags: php, static-files

I'm working on a project where we need to store static files (user images, videos, etc.) on a different server (nginx serves static files). I haven't worked with a separate static file server before, so I don't even know how to save/edit/delete user files on a remote server.

Any links, suggestions, hints would be greatly appreciated.

thank you!

UPD. Debian Lenny 5.0, standard http, Apache, Nginx, PHP 5.2

Comment: What protocol/s are you planning on using? what OS? what server software? You need to give us more information.

Answer (score 1):

The [filesystem section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php) of the PHP docs.